# app packed with pyinstaller don't open file from temporary directory (tkinter, tksvg, tempfile)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, temporary-files

Hi everyone I have a problem with a simple app (at least the MRE is simple) packed with pyinstaller.
This desktop app should display a simple SVG file (I use tksvg).
My app first writes SVG into a temporary directory (writing is not as simple as in MRE), and then in the right moment displays it. It works nicely until I've packed it with pyinstaller.
My full app console throws me an error that the file can't be found. The path always ends with \tksvg. And such directory don't exist.
It looks as if tksvg would create such a subfolder but pyinstaller is missing such instructions?
Any ideas on what can I do?
Warning, total noob.
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
import tempfile
import tksvg

root = Tk()

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print(temp_dir.name)
with open(temp_dir.name + f'\\test.svg', 'w') as a_file:
    a_file.write('<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400"><rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400"    fill="red" /></svg>')

svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(file=temp_dir.name + f'\\test.svg')
show_svg = Label(root, image=svg_image)
show_svg.pack()


mainloop()
```

Edit

After some fight with the subject, I'm certain that it must be an issue with how pyinstaller packs libraries, a specially tksvg.
Method proposed by @JRiggles in itself works, but not with tksvg objects, and it's not necessary in my case (I use a temporary directory to manage files).
To check if the temporary directory works also when packed (pyinstaller), I've created "jpeg viewer" script and it works perfectly, even using PIL libraries.

```
from tkinter import *
import tempfile
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()


temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print(temp_dir.name)  # just to check if temp. dir. was created

jpeg_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("jpeg file", "*.jpeg")])  # opening file from disc
picture = Image.open(jpeg_file)  # reading it with PIL library
picture.save(temp_dir.name+'\\test.jpeg')  # saving image to temp. dir.

an_image = Image.open(temp_dir.name + '\\test.jpeg')  # opening image from temp.dir.
the_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(an_image)  # reading image

show_image = Label(root, image=the_image)  # setting label as "display"
show_image.pack()  # showing the image


mainloop()
```

Does anyone has experience with SVG libraries, tksvg or any other, and how to make exe. with them?

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller places your assets (images, icons, whatever) in a special directory that's created in your temp dir at runtime. I use this `fetch_resource` function to dynamically load assets when running a pyinstaller executable

```Python
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def fetch_resource(rsrc_path):
    """Loads resources from the temp dir used by pyinstaller executables"""
    try:
        base_path = Path(sys._MEIPASS)
    except AttributeError:
        return rsrc_path  # not running as exe, just return the unaltered path
    else:
        return base_path.joinpath(rsrc_path)
```

In your case, you would use it like so:

```Python
svg_path = fetch_resource(r'path\to\test.svg')
with open(svg_path, 'w') as a_file:
...
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(file=svg_path)
```

You'll need to tell pyinstaller where to locate any files you want to 'fetch' by using the `--add-data` command-line *or* by adding the path to the `datas` list in your `*.spec` file

Comment: Hi, I can't make this work. Can you show an exact path that could work for this MRE script (not 'path\to\test\svg.')? And a command for pyinstaller. Because now I'm creating a folder that is using the absolute path and not one in the temporary directory. THX

Comment: I can't give you an exact path because I don't know how your project is structured or where any of your files are. You'll need to replace `path\to\test.svg` with whatever the actual path to that file is *on your machine*. Are you building with pyinstaller from a `*.spec` file or are you doing everything from the command line?

Comment: Ok, from the beginnig. In script I should have relative path 'to/test.svg'. In location of my script I should have folder 'to'. In pyinstaller I should point to (--add-data) location of that folder on my system. Is that correct? By the way I use auto-py-to-exe.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Auto-Py-to-Exe should show something along the lines of `--add-data ".\path\to;path"` in the "command" window

Comment: Still no luck, it gives me back error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI288002\\tksvg'  It looks like something with tksvg library. Did you try to run it on your machine?

Comment: So I've made some further tests. @JRiggles method worked only if I replace SVG file with anything else, so I could omit tksvg library. What's more, I was able even to omit the whole method with _MEIPASS folder. I was able to create temporary directory (tempfile) write to it and read from it a text file. Pyinstaller didn't have any issue with that also. I suspect that pyinstaller don't load tksvg libraries to _MEIPASS, so when I run script the error about missing file/directory is not about fetching my data but fetching libraries.

Answer (score 1):

After some time it turn out that it was enough to add  --collect-all="tksvg" to the pyinstaller. Maybe you could be more specific about what was missing in the compiled pack, but I have no competence to judge it, so I went for a safe collect-all.
THX

Answer (score 0):

Use add data or edit your spec file to add the tksvg package to your dist folder.

eg:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --w add-data= 'env/Lib/site-packages/tksvg/*';'tksvg' myscript.py
```

OR

eg: in spec file

```
datas = ['env/Lib/site-packages/tksvg/*','tksvg']
```

This worked for me. You can even simply copy the tksvg package folder and paste it in the dist folder.

Neither hidden imports nor adding the package path to pathex worked before I tried this.